# how to make javascript parent element like onclick this.parentElement

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new on javascript and having a problem with this.

onclick="this.parentElement.style.width='100%',style.overflow='hidden'"
onclick="this.parentElement.style.width='200%',style.overflow='scroll'"

my question is, how to make a script function on html looks like that's onclick="this.parentElement....." (only parent element)
because if only using function indeximg() document.getElementById one click is zooming all image on index.html

Comment: If I’m understanding correctly, you are trying to select only one image rather than all the images?

Comment: yep, only one image on parent element.

Comment: @ZenSama can u please rephrase the question?

Comment: Please update your question and include a [mcve].